# Issue with Event Log file. Users activities related to Dashboard view are not recorded in Salesforce

Tags: dashboard, developer, workbench, eventlogfile

We have Enabled Event log for our organization and it was working absolutely fine but since last month Sales profile Dashboard view activities do not record in event log. I queried event log used below link

"https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/"

and check so no activity related to Sales profile getting recorded. I raised a case in Salesforce but they closed my case to said it's a developer issue and you have only basic support. I don't think so it's a developer issue. 
can any one help me out to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got following conclusion on Event log dashboard.

As per my finding if dashboard set as a “Run as specified user” so whoever are refreshing the dashboard log getting generated for that users who set as a specific user.

Let says, if I created a dashboard and my name set as “Run as specific user” and If you refreshed the dashboard. log getting generated with my ID and name instead of your ID and name.

I already had a word with tier 3 Salesforce support and they said it's working as per design and i need dynamic dashboards.